# Typescript error on $(this).closest("form").valid()

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, typescript

I have the typings for jquery and jquery.validation but stil get an error on $(this).closest("form").valid()
The property 'valid' does not exist on value of type 'JQuery'
Is there a typing I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: did you include the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: To include the validate plugin, add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
` after jQuery library is included

Comment: Also, please be more mindful when tagging.  The jQuery Validation Engine is not the jQuery Validation plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: As Arun asked, have you remembered to properly include the jQuery Validate plugin?  Otherwise, the `.valid()` method is not part of the standard jQuery library.

Comment: Thanks, validation works ok, just in typescript I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Help yourself fix:

```
interface JQuery{
    valid:any;
}
```

## Better fix:

Use this definition: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery.validation/jquery.validation.d.ts

## Whats in the definition

The important sections from this definition (Don't copy paste ... just pointing out the community effort)

```
interface JQuery
{
    /**
     * Remove the specified attributes from the first matched element and return them.
     * 
     * @param attributes A space-seperated list of attribute names to remove.
     */
    removeAttrs(attributes: string): any;

    /**
     * Returns the validations rules for the first selected element
     */
    rules(): any;

    /**
     * Removes the specified rules and returns all rules for the first matched element.
     * 
     * @param command "remove"
     * @param rules Removes and returns all rules. Manipulates only rules specified via rules-option or via rules("add").
     */
    rules(command: string): any;
    /**
     * Removes the specified rules and returns all rules for the first matched element.
     * 
     * @param command "remove"
     * @param rules The space-separated names of rules to remove and return. Manipulates only rules specified via rules-option or via rules("add").
     */
    rules(command: string, rules: string): any;
    /**
     * Adds the specified rules and returns all rules for the first matched element. Requires that the parent form is validated, that is, $("form").validate() is called first 
     * 
     * @param command "add"
     * @param rules The rules to add. Accepts the same format as the rules-option of the validate-method.
     */
    rules(command: string, rules: Object): any;

    /**
     * Checks whether the selected form is valid or whether all selected elements are valid.
     */
    valid(): boolean;

    /**
     * Validates the selected form.
     * 
     * @param options options for validation
     */
    validate(options?: ValidationOptions): Validator;
}
```

## For future

You need to use a definition for every library you use.

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the definition file and could see Valid:boolean, but would not work no matter how many times I compiled or restated visual studio.
This morning after restating visual studio error went away
Thanks